# ESP8266 stack trace: find position of "last failed alloc call" in code

Tags: stack-trace, esp8266

I'm trying to debug a large sketch, I'm occasionally getting a crash related to the web interface, and am trying to find out where exactly this is going wrong.

The stack trace ends with:

```
last failed alloc call: 4022D552(1480)
```

This particular address is not present in the decode stack trace itself, but may hold the key to finding the source of the problem. Any suggestions on how to track this one down?

```
Decoding 36 results
0x402222c5: BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::_installClientX509Validator() at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h line 986
:  (inlined by) ?? at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h line 316
:  (inlined by) ?? at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h line 598
:  (inlined by) ?? at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h line 614
:  (inlined by) BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::_installClientX509Validator() at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp line 877
0x40222cfc: BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::_connectSSL(char const*) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp line 962
0x40219c70: esp_yield at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp line 91
0x4021a8c3: delay at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring.cpp line 54
0x40206d6d: WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, unsigned short) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/include/ClientContext.h line 136
:  (inlined by) WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, unsigned short) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClient.cpp line 170
0x40222eed: BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned short) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp line 231
0x40225230: BearSSL::PrivateKey::getEC() const at ?? line ?
0x40225230: BearSSL::PrivateKey::getEC() const at ?? line ?
0x40216b5c: HTTPClient::connect() at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp line 1165
0x4021c16e: uart_write at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/uart.cpp line 498
0x40217820: HTTPClient::sendRequest(char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned int) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp line 655
0x40217d98: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 158
0x40273eba: sleep_reset_analog_rtcreg_8266 at ?? line ?
0x402180a5: Print::write(char const*) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/Print.h line 60
0x40217d83: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 154
0x402179ba: HTTPClient::GET() at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp line 575
0x402118e8: HydroMonitorLogging::sendPostData(char*) at /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorLogging.cpp line 730
0x40225470: BearSSL::PrivateKey::getEC() const at ?? line ?
0x4022c4c0: _vsprintf_r at /home/earle/src/esp-quick-toolchain/repo/newlib/newlib/libc/stdio/vsprintf.c line 65
0x40217d98: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 158
0x4022000a: spiffs_object_truncate at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/spiffs/spiffs_nucleus.cpp line 1727
0x40211d41: HydroMonitorLogging::transmitMessages() at /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorLogging.cpp line 337
0x40211caa: HydroMonitorLogging::transmitMessages() at /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorLogging.cpp line 326
0x40204dab: handleAPI() at /home/wouter/Arduino/Williams_fridge/Fridge_control/webAPI.ino line 149
0x402251c8: BearSSL::PrivateKey::getEC() const at ?? line ?
0x40217d98: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 158
0x40218130: Print::println() at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/Print.cpp line 178
0x402121b5: HydroMonitorLogging::logData() at /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorLogging.cpp line 250
0x40217d83: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 154
0x40224948: Print::write(char) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/Print.h line 73
0x40218114: Print::print(char) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/Print.cpp line 126
0x402106f4: HydroMonitorIsolatedSensorBoard::readSensor(bool) at /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorIsolatedSensorBoard.cpp line 36
0x40207a07: TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int) at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp line 134
0x402042f9: loop at /home/wouter/Arduino/Williams_fridge/Fridge_control/loop.ino line 36
0x40219d20: loop_wrapper() at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp line 125
0x401015d5: cont_wrapper at /home/wouter/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/cont.S line 81
```

Note: I also asked [on the esp8266 forum](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=19815), and [opened an issue on github](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/6146) about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the free heap and got around 32 kB. So didn't expect any memory issues.

Turns out, 32 kB is less than 17 kB + 5 kB - for clientSecure and server respectively. And that's what caused the crashes. Dropping SSL encryption completely solved the problem. The development team mentioned it must be contiguous memory - which for whatever reason that 32 kB of mine apparently isn't.

Simple conclusion: you can not run the server (just http - no encryption) AND have a secure client in the same program.

No AJAX, by the way. Haven't gotten around to that level yet.

Answer (score 0):

Intermittent ESP crashes are most often due to running out of RAM. A "failed alloc call" likely refers to a failure to allocate memory for an operation (encryption takes a good bit, as does every open request in the queue). The stack trace will not point to a specific spot in your code because client libraries run "in the background" (triggered by interrupts or once-per-loop calls to a function that does everything) and no specific event in your firmware caused it. On a memory-starved ESP with a long response time, sending several AJAX requests at once from the frontend can cause the overload.

To see whether this is the case, try printing the result of `ESP.getFreeHeap()` at various points in your loop. If it falls much below 10kb, there is a risk that another request will drive it over the edge.